# Drop numbers in string column stored as object and convert to string Python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, string, type-conversion, sklearn-pandas

I have a variable stored as an object in a dataframe which is a string field that also contains numbers for some rows:

```
ID  Var1
1   abcd
2   eftg
3   -1234-
4   zxct
```

How could I drop numbers for ID 3 and replace them with other letters or leave it blank? Desired output:

```
ID  Var1
1   abcd
2   eftg
3   
4   zxct
```

or

```
ID  Var1
1   abcd
2   eftg
3   aaaa
4   zxct
```

I tried to stored Var1 as string with:

```
df['Var1'] = df['Var1'].astype(str)
```

But it's not working, what am I missing?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension to check the type of each column-entry and replace non-strings. To replace strings consisting only numerical characters I recommend Series.str.isnumeric().

```
import pandas as pd

# replace everything but strings with empty strings
df =pd.DataFrame({'Var1':['aa', 'bb', 12, 'cc']}, index=[1,2,3,4]) # create dataframe
is_no_string = [not isinstance(val, str) for val in df.Var1] # check wether value is no string
df.loc[is_no_string] = '' # replace values that contain no strings with empty strings

# replace every string consisting only of numeric characters with empty string
df =pd.DataFrame({'Var1':['aa', 'bb', '12', 'cc']}, index=[1,2,3,4]) # create dataframe
is_numeric = df.Var1.str.isnumeric() # check whether all characters in each string are numeric
df.loc[is_numeric] = '' # replace numeric strings with empty strings
```

I think `df['Var1'] = df['Var1'].astype(str)` works fine for converting numbers to strings (look at the output of the following code).To acess the type of single entrys of a column of a dataframe acess those elements and use type() on them.

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'Var1':['aa', 'bb', 12, 'cc']}, index=[1,2,3,4]) # create dataframe

print(df.Var1.dtype) # columns containing strings are stored as objects 
print(type(df.Var1[1])) # those objects can contain strings and numbers
print(type(df.Var1[3]))
print(df.Var1.to_numpy())

df.Var1 = df.Var1.astype(str)
print(df.Var1.dtype) # column is still object
print(type(df.Var1[1])) 
print(type(df.Var1[3])) # but integer was changed to string
print(df.Var1.to_numpy())

# Output
object
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
['aa' 'bb' 12 'cc']

object
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
['aa' 'bb' '12' 'cc']
```